# Unable to run schemas on mySQL in MacBook Air

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

i have recently started a PDG Data science course online. We're learning about mySQL workbench. So i've installed it but when i import a database onto it, i'm not able to run the schemas nor get any output. I keep getting an error saying datatype not valid or something along those lines. This is weird cuz it works fine for the guy teaching the course. When i try to do the exact same thing it doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on MacBook Air. I tried uninstall MySQL, Workbench, but doesn't work.

the solution for me is:

quit workbench
in Terminal:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/MySQL/Workbench/

rm wb_state.xml

rm wb_options.xml
which reset workbench setting and configurations
```

start workbench again. everything back to normal